# Html5 <nav> tag use

Tags: html, nav

Can we use `<nav>` tag with the rest of `<header>` tag in HTML 5?

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @user465825: could you be a bit more specific about what you mean?

Answer (score 5):

The HTML5 spec has [an example](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) where a `nav` element is a child of a `header` element, so yes.

Answer (score 3):

The `<nav>` tag can be used to wrap **any** navigational links. Whether those links are in the header or the footer or otherwise in the page, if they are a distinct section for navigation, those links can be grouped within a `<nav>` tag.

See http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_nav.asp

Answer (score 3):

if it is a main menu in the top part of the web page use it inside the header

```
 <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
 </header>
```

also you can use the nav in the footer ..  if this navigation is of "Primary Importance" like the top menu

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/) states the following:

> The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other
>   pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.
>   Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a nav element only
>   sections that consist of major navigation blocks are appropriate for
>   the nav element. In particular, it is common for footers to have a
>   list of links to various key parts of a site, but the footer element
>   is more appropriate in such cases, and no nav element is necessary for
>   those links.

The [nav tag](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element) **should not** be used to wrap all forms of navigation and is reserved for '**Major Navigation**'

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
<header>
    <a href="#" id="logo" ></a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">ling1</a>
        <a href="#">link2</a>
        <a href="#">link3</a>
        <a href="#">link4</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```